# Join with update/delete WSO2 CEP Event Table Using Siddhi

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-cep

I have a userStream having `name,address,status`

I want to store this details in `UserDetailsTable` (In memory table)

Result of UserDetailsTable is below

```
"Jose",  "address1","false" 
"Rockey","address2","false" 
"sibin", "address3","false"
```

I have another `triggerStream` having name,triggerStatus

```
"Rockey","delete"
"Jose"  ,"update"
```

**Case 1)** 
When `triggerStream` comes as "Rockey", I want to join this triggerStream with `UserDetailsTable` according to (name and triggerStatus) and delete the row from UserDetailsTable.

**Case 2)** When `triggerStream` comes as "Jose", I want to join this `triggerStream` with `UserDetailsTable` according to (name and triggerStatus) and update the status as "true" in UserDetailsTable.

Final state of UserDetailsTable is below.

```
"Jose",  "address1","true"
"sibin", "address3","false"
```

how can able to do this with WSO2 CEP?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've defined the streams and tables and an insert query to populate the in-memory table.

For case 1, you can use a delete query as follows with a condition:

```
from triggerStream 
delete userDetailsTable
on name == userDetailsTable.name and triggerStatus == userDetailsTable.status;
```

If you want to delete specific names such as 'rockey' you can add a filter to the above query as follows:

```
from triggerStream[name == 'rockey'] 
delete userDetailsTable
on name == userDetailsTable.name and triggerStatus == userDetailsTable.status;
```

For case 2, you can use an update query with a filter for 'jose' as follows:

```
from triggerStream[name == 'jose']
select name, triggerStatus as status 
update userDetailsTable on name == userDetailsTable.name
```

in this query, we rename the attribute 'triggerStatus' as 'status' to make it equal to table's attribute name.